# How to get all records of a dynamodb table with partiql without having click "Continue Search" button

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

A simple select statement in dynamoDB only returns 31 rows at a time. I want all the records at once without having to click "Continue Search" button.  Or at least tell me for sure that it cant be done.  I cant find the answer to either question.

Answer (score 0):

The continue search button is there to safe-guard you from consuming too much capacity. Imagine you had a 50TB table and you ran a Scan, it would take a long time and cost a lot of capacity units.

If you're looking for SQL style queries on your DynamoDB table without having to paginate manually, then I suggest using the [Athena DynamoDB Connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-dynamodb.html)

> The Amazon Athena DynamoDB connector enables Amazon Athena to communicate with DynamoDB so that you can query your tables with SQL.